# Apache case sensitive syntax in httpd.conf file

Tags: apache-2.4

Can we write the Apache server syntax as `serverroot` instead of `ServerRoot` in the config file?

Note: I just mention an example and is this possible like other syntax as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote [from the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/configuring.html#syntax):

> Directives in the configuration files are case-insensitive, but arguments to directives are often case sensitive.

So, yes, you can write `serverroot` instead of `ServerRoot`. But that might not be true for arguments.

Comment: Hi Gerald ,Thanks for your reply even i tested practically in my local and it's working fine as well.
But what exactly arguments means here?
Suppose KeepAlive Off is same as in httpd.conf file..can i mentioned as 
keepalive off
is this kind of argument you are talking about or some other thing?if others please explain me a bit more

Comment: The documentation isn't more specific. I would assume that values like "On", "Off", "True", "False" etc. are case **in**sensitive, while values that reference actual names (e. g. user or group names in authentication, or file system paths) are case sensitive. But this is just a guess on my side.

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful if the documentation was clearer on this.  For example: `ReWriteEngine On` vs `ReWriteEngine on` vs `rewriteengine on`.